# Using Intent with scheme to launch app android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get a web URL to open / launch an activity for my application, but it isn't working. The URL is something similar to the following:

https://zzz.yyy.com/activate?user="123123123"&token="absdi24"

I only need the link to be recognized up to the point of "activate". I set my intent up as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="zzz.yyy.com"
            android:path="/activate*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I have tried this code with and without the wild-card (*) at the end of the 'path' and nothing has  worked so far. What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:path` is a literal complete path. Try `android:pathPrefix` or `android:pathPattern` -- in this case, `pathPrefix` would seem to be sufficient.

Comment: That worked out perfectly! Thank you!

Now, if I wanted to retrieve that entire link, because the token or account name are important information, is there way to grab the link that was passed into the intent?

Comment: @RyanInBinary: `getIntent().getData()` will give you the `Uri` associated with the `Intent` used to start your activity. There's a chance that it will leave off the stuff starting with the `?` -- I know you cannot filter on query parameters, but I am uncertain whether or not they are still retained on the `Uri` that is supplied to you. If they *are* stripped off, you will need to consider rewriting your URL to be more REST-y (e.g., `https://zzz.yyy.com/user/123123123/activate/absdi24`).

Comment: This was correct. And if it helps anyone else, using the getQuery from the data URI returns token=absdi24.

Thank you again for all of your help! Wish I could upvote you again

Comment: @RyanInBinary: Ah, yes, I forgot about `getQuery()` -- I so rarely see it used, as this is about the only scenario in which it is relevant.